# Pandas split values of a row into two different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three rows. I would like to take half from the middle row and add that to the top and bottom. Example dataframe below:

```
data = {'A':  [3, 2, 4],
        'B': [3, 5, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B'])
```

From this data frame, how would I be able to split the second row (A: 2, B: 5) into the other rows so that the output would be

```
data_output = {'A':  [4, 5],
        'B': [5.5, 6.5]}

df_output = pd.DataFrame(data_output, columns = ['A','B'])
```

My current thoughts are to get the row divide that by 2 add to the other rows append and subset.

```
x = df.loc[0, ] + df.loc[1, ]/2
y = df.loc[2, ] + df.loc[1, ]/2

df2 = df.append([x, y], ignore_index=True)
df2.loc[3:]
```

However, if I wanted to keep a much larger dataframe or operate over multiple instances this seems inefficient. Any thoughts how to split the value of a row and add the split values to the row above and below it?

Comment: Do you want to split only the 2nd row into two halfs and assign one portion to 1st and the other to 3rd?

Comment: Hi @JoeFerndz, in this example yes, the code in the third block does this, but it seems like a very inefficient way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this if this operation is on a single row:

```
row = 1 #index
df.update(df.loc[[row-1,row+1]].add(df.loc[row].div(2)))
out = df.drop(row).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print(out)

     A    B
0  4.0  5.5
1  5.0  6.5
```

Or for a copy instead of manipulating the original df:

```
row = 1
(df.loc[[row-1,row+1]].add(df.loc[row].div(2)).reindex(df.index)
                   .fillna(df).drop(row).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: Thanks @anky, this is beautiful! Exactly what I needed and I port this into a function, you are awesome!